# Object not being remove from my Array on check

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

**http://plnkr.co/edit/b1v87pUEykOJnM4HLFKz?p=preview**

[image]

I have 2 arrays, one will come in via an API `apiArray`

The 2nd array `toggleArray` will be a container of items I choose from `apiArray`

I'm trying to toggle which items are in and out of the array by the `selectBtn` function.

Right now I'm able to add items into my `toggleArray` however clicking on the same button does not remove the item, they stay in the array.

What's a better way to do the check if not in Array then add, if in Array then remove?

```
var vs = $scope;
    vs.message = "Add and remove objects from array:";
    vs.toggleArray = [];
    var btnInArray = false;

    vs.apiArray = [
        { name: 'AAA' },
        { name: 'BBB' },
        { name: 'CCC' }
      ];

    vs.selectBtn = function(btnObj) {
      console.log(btnObj.name);

    function checkUpdateToggleTags(obj, list) {
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                if (list[i] === obj) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        btnInArray = checkUpdateToggleTags(btnObj, vs.toggleArray);

        if (btnInArray) {

            // check the toggleArray and if obj from listToDelete is there
            // remove that obj from toggleArray
            for(var i = 0; i < vs.toggleArray.length; i++) {
                var obj = vs.toggleArray[i];

                if (vs.toggleArray.indexOf(obj.term) !== -1) {
                    vs.toggleArray.splice(i, 1);
                    i--;
                }
            }

        } else {
          vs.toggleArray.push(btnObj);
        }

        console.log(btnInArray);
        console.log(vs.toggleArray);
    };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made everything too complicated. To find object in array you can use [Array.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) directly, as it allows to search for non-primitive types too. In this case `selectBtn` method will become as simple as this:

```
vs.selectBtn = function(btnObj) {
    var index = vs.toggleArray.indexOf(btnObj);
    if (index !== -1) {
        vs.toggleArray.splice(index, 1);
    } 
    else {
        vs.toggleArray.push(btnObj);
    }
};
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/34KVRAAhuMdVteO9S1Qn?p=preview

Comment: Haha yeah I did ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°) been coding too long today... thanks!